# Compare function ( ==, all.equal) is not working properly when it comes to two digit numbers in R?

Tags: r, igraph

I am trying to compare two number in my code, when it comes to compare one digit number , it works fine whether I use `==` or `all.equall` function, but when it comes to comparing 2 digit number or more like 17, it can't say they are the same, I have already go through this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508518/why-are-these-numbers-not-equal) and `all.equall` is not working as well. beside my numbers are all integers. can any one tell me what the problem is here ?

I'll put the code here so the problem can be reproducible.

```
library(igraph)
node1<- c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,7,8,9,9,10,12,14,14,17,17,19)
node2<-c(2,3,4,5,6,17,12,14,7,8,6,13,14,9,10,11,11,13,16,15,18,19,20)
AZADEH_GRAPH.data <- data.frame(node1,node2)
dataframe_AZADEH_GRAPH<-AZADEH_GRAPH
graph_AZADEH_GRAPH=graph.data.frame(dataframe_AZADEH_GRAPH,directed=FALSE)
Nodes1_AZADEH_GRAPH<- replicate(vcount(graph_AZADEH_GRAPH), 0)
SuperEgo_AZADEH_GRAPH<- list()
Com_AZADEH_GRAPH<- list()
community_member <-matrix()
neghbor_list<-list()
count_neighbors<-list()
community_1<-list()


SuperEgo_AZADEH_GRAPH[[2]]=make_ego_graph(graph_AZADEH_GRAPH,2,
V(graph_AZADEH_GRAPH)$name[2],
mode = "all",mindist = 0)
Com_AZADEH_GRAPH[[2]] <- cluster_infomap(SuperEgo_AZADEH_GRAPH[[2]][[1]])
community_member<-data.matrix(membership(Com_AZADEH_GRAPH[[2]]))
neghbor_list[2]=ego(graph_AZADEH_GRAPH, order = 1, 
nodes = V(graph_AZADEH_GRAPH)$name[2], mode = "all",mindist = 1)
count_neighbors[2]=length(neghbor_list[[2]])
for (k in 1:nrow(community_member))
{
  RRR<-cbind(community_member,as.integer(rownames(community_member)[k]))
}

for (n in 1:nrow(RRR))
{
  RRR[n,2]<-as.integer(rownames(RRR)[n])
}

for (i in 1: length(neghbor_list[[2]]))
{
  for (j in 1:nrow(RRR))
  {
    if (neghbor_list[[2]][i]==RRR[[j,2]])
    {
      community_1[i]=RRR[[j,1]]
    }
  }
}
```

the problem is with `if statements` and more specifically when `i=3` and `j=6` `neghbor_list[[2]][3]`,
`RRR[[6,2]]` both return `17` but still it gives `False` it is working fine when `i=1 & 2`

Comment: Please try `identical`

Comment: I have check identical as well, when the number is 17 in both..it is not working.

Comment: @jogo the code above is reproducible , isn't it ?

Comment: I got an error running the code: `Error in simple_vs_index(x, ii, na_ok) : Unknown vertex selected`.

Comment: @jogo I've change the code and put the sample data inside it and explain the issue with example

Comment: @nicola.. I have chnage the code

Comment: Actually `neghbor_list[[2]][i]` is 12. See it with `str(neghbor_list[[2]][i])`.

Comment: @nicola yeah,but still I can't understand why this is happening.

Comment: If this was a typo or the problem is no longer reproducible then you should delete the question.

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted solution on behalf of the question author)*.

The issue is found, it was referring to the indexes, I should have use `$name` instead after `neghbor_list[[2]][3]`.